# JDBC DAO SQL case-insensitive query

Tags: postgresql, case-insensitive, spring-framework-beans

IDE: IntelliJ
SDK: JAVA 11.0
SQL Client: postgreSQL

My DAO contains the following @Override and I'm running into a case-insensitive issue. As much as I try, I have not been able to figure out how to make the postgreSQL search case-insensitive. My testing condition is also at the bottom.  Any suggestions?

```
    @Override
    public List<Employee> searchEmployeesByName(String firstNameSearch, String lastNameSearch) {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT employee_id, department_id, first_name, last_name, birth_date, hire_date " +
                "FROM employee " +
                "WHERE first_name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?;";
        firstNameSearch = "%" + firstNameSearch + "%";
        lastNameSearch = "%" + lastNameSearch + "%";

        SqlRowSet results = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(sql, firstNameSearch, lastNameSearch);
        while (results.next()) {
            employees.add(mapRowToEmployee(results));
        }
        return employees;
    }


    @Test
    public void employee_added_to_project_is_in_list_of_employees_for_project() {
        sut.addEmployeeToProject(1L, 3L);
        List<Employee> employees = sut.getEmployeesByProjectId(1L);
        Assert.assertEquals("addEmployeeToProject didn't increase number of employees assigned to project",
            2, employees.size());
        assertEmployeesMatch("addEmployeeToProject assigned wrong employee to project", EMPLOYEE_3, employees.get(1));
    }
```

Comment: Since the answer solved your issue you should accept it. This helps future questioners that have the same issue (knowing that an answer worked), and it removed the question from the unanswered queue. Please do not leave satisfactorily answered questions as unanswered.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow and I'm just learning how it all works. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want case-insensitive matches with PostgreSQL, use [`ILIKE` instead of `LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-matching.html):

> The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard but is a PostgreSQL extension.

Comment: Done! It worked and passed the test! Thanks, @Bruno!